# Save screen capture in pyvista including interaction / rotation

Tags: python, data-visualization, vtk, pyvista

I'm looking for a way to effectively capture the frame buffer *during interaction* in `pyvista` so that I can produce a video afterwards of the model moving around on the screen.

The problem I've encountered is that when I click the screen to interact with the viewer/plotter, no frames are written while the mouse button is pressed and the model is moving to its next position. This results in 'jerky' movements in the video.

Is there a way around this behavior to effectively do something like a screen capture of the plotter window, even when being manipulated? Maybe through direct access to the frame buffer or something similar?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np
from pyvista import examples

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

px = int(round(1920*0.4))
py = int(round(1000*0.4))

mesh = examples.download_st_helens().warp_by_scalar()

p = pv.Plotter()
p.set_background(color='k')
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
p.add_mesh(mesh, lighting=True, texture=False, cmap=cmap, smooth_shading=True)
p.show_grid()
p.show(window_size=[px,py], auto_close=False, interactive_update=True)
p.render()
p.open_movie('anim.mp4',framerate=60)

i=0
while (i<100):
    i+=1
    p.write_frame()
    print(i)

p.close()
```

[image]

Comment: The only really easy solution I have found for this is to create a repeating timer and in the callback perform the interaction, render and save the frame. The video gets smooth, but you need to plan the interaction (say a rotation) beforehand.

Comment: This is completely beside the point, but you don't have to pass `viridis` because that's the default, and even if it weren't you could pass it by just `cmap='viridis'`.

Comment: @JensMunk do you have an example?

Comment: I have an example where I use VTK directly, which is what `pyvista` uses under the hood. Would you like that.

Comment: I'd appreciate it! I've played around a bit with the `vtk` library in python but quickly discovered that it's not quite as user-friendly as `pyvista` and haven't had the tiem to dig too deeply into it. For the time being I'd say a working solution in `vtk` would be the accepted answer here!

Comment: Ping @JensMunk ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added an example in pure VTK, where a cube is rotated and a smooth video is captured with the rotation. Afterwards, the interactor is started and the user can interact with the scene afterwards.

```
import os
import vtk
import numpy as np

def vtkRotationMovie(renderWindow, filename='c:/test.avi'):
  global degrees
  degrees = 0

  windowToImageFilter = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
  windowToImageFilter.SetInput(renderWindow)
  windowToImageFilter.SetInputBufferTypeToRGB()
  windowToImageFilter.ReadFrontBufferOff()
  windowToImageFilter.Update()

  if os.name == 'nt':
    writer = vtk.vtkAVIWriter()
  else:
    writer = vtk.vtkOggTheoraWriter()
  writer.SetInputConnection(windowToImageFilter.GetOutputPort())
  writer.SetRate(10) # Not needed for Ogg

  try:
    os.remove(filename)
  except OSError:
    pass
  writer.SetFileName(filename)
  writer.Start()

  timerId = renderWindow.GetInteractor().CreateRepeatingTimer(50)
  def cb(interactor, event):
    global degrees
    step = 5
    if (degrees > 359):
      interactor.DestroyTimer(timerId)
      writer.End()
      return
    interactor.GetRenderWindow().Render()
    cam = interactor.GetRenderWindow().GetRenderers().GetFirstRenderer().GetActiveCamera()
    cam.Azimuth(step)
    cam.OrthogonalizeViewUp()
    windowToImageFilter.Modified()
    writer.Write()
    degrees = degrees + step
  renderWindow.GetInteractor().AddObserver('TimerEvent', cb)
  renderWindow.GetInteractor().Start()

# create a rendering window and renderer
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

# create a renderwindowinteractor
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# create cube
cube = vtk.vtkCubeSource()

# mapper
cubeMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cubeMapper.SetInputConnection(cube.GetOutputPort())

# actor
cubeActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cubeActor.SetMapper(cubeMapper)

# assign actor to the renderer
ren.AddActor(cubeActor)
ren.SetBackground(.3,.2,.1)
# enable user interface interactor
iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()

vtkRotationMovie(renWin, filename='./test.avi')

iren.Start()
```

Comment: Note that for recorded paths one can use [orbiting](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/02-plot/orbit.html) with pyvista.